# Select MD5 data from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, md5

I have a MySQL table that contains raw, un-encrypted data. What I need to do is select the username using it's MD5 encrypted hash.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='MD5 HASH HERE' LIMIT 1;
```

How does one go about searching a SQL database using MD5 hashed data?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE MD5(username)='MD5 HASH HERE' LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MD5(username)='MD5 HASH HERE' LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE md5(username)='MD5 HASH HERE' LIMIT 1;
```